# Почему мой код не работает?

Tags: c++, олимпиада, множества, set

Во входной строке записана последовательность чисел через пробел. Для каждого числа выведите слово `YES` (в отдельной строке), если это число ранее встречалось в последовательности или `NO`, если не встречалось.

**Входные данные**

Вводится число N - количество элементов списка, а затем N чисел.

**Выходные данные**

Выведите ответ на задачу.

**Sample Input:**

```
6
1 2 3 2 3 4
```

**Sample Output:**

```
NO
NO
NO
YES
YES
NO
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n, c, d, x = 0;
    cin >> n;
    multiset <int> s;
    set <int> s2;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> x;
        s.insert(x);
    }

    for(auto now: s){

        c = s2.size();

        s2.insert(now);

        d = s2.size();

        if(c < d){
            cout << "NO" << endl;   
        }
        else if (c == d) {
            cout << "YES" << endl;   
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

**Мой результат:**

```
NO
NO
YES
NO
YES
NO
```

Comment: `multiset` сортирует элементы по возврастанию (если не указать другой порядок). Непонятно, зачем он вам тут. Взяли бы `std::vector` или, еще лучше, вообще не использовали лишний контейнер.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  `multiset` необходим для хранения не уникальных данных, иначе, я думаю, при заполнении обычного множества, я просто потеряю часть данных

Comment: Почему не `set` - понятно. Непонятно, почему не `vector`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat на самом деле я не учёл того, что `multiset` сортирует значения, поэтому и использовал его. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 4):

Знаете, ваш код как-то даже не хочется комментировать. Разве что - *зачем просто, если можно сложно?*

Вы хотите `set`? Нет вопросов:

```
int main() {

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    set <int> s;

    for(int x; n-->0;)
    {
        cin >> x;
        cout << (s.insert(x).second ? "NO\n" : "YES\n");
    }
}
```

P.S. Ладно, по вашему коду. Подумайте, **в каком порядке** выполняется обход элементов `multiset`?

P.P.S. [Здесь](https://informatics.mccme.ru/moodle/mod/statements/view3.php?chapterid=3752#1) `N` не задается, и решение еще короче:

```
int main()
{
    set <int> s;
    for(int x; cin >> x;)
        cout << (s.insert(x).second ? "NO" : "YES") << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Задача требует решения через множества

Comment: Ну, а я как решал? :)